# Calculating mean and standard deviation for raster values using whole pixels within a polygon

Tags: raster, shapefile, polygon, r

I have a raster image and a corresponding shapefile. I would like to calculate the statistics of the values within polygons which have a common attribute but only using pixels which are fully contained in the polygons.

I would like to do this in R, however I have so far only managed to load the image and shapefile using readGDAl and readOGR respectively!

Comment: And you have looked into the `raster` package? Specifically the function `extract` ?

Comment: @Curlew, when i use the function extract, i get an error report saying 'unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"SpatialGridDataFrame"

Comment: Rather than answer as a Comment I would recommend revising your Question with the additional details people ask for by using the edit button.

Comment: @Noella, just convert it into an `raster` object beforehand for instance with function `raster(...)`.